# Efficient way to compute the next higher integer after a float?

Tags: c++, c

Surprisingly I can't find an easy reference on this, I want to compute:

```
float x = /*...*/;
float next = nextint(x);
```

where next is strictly greater than `x` (ie if `x` is an integer, return the next higher integer). Ideally without branches.

Comment: Are you after [`ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil)? Also if it's an int wouldn't this just be `++x`? It would help if you added examples

Comment: What do you mean "if `x` is an integer"? Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I think they mean `2.5 -> 3.0` but also `4.0 -> 5.0`

Comment: @tadman OP wants `nextint(1.000)` to be 2.000.

Comment: Sorry but it is same to assume that `std::ceil` already uses the best way to do this. Especially since it can use implementation depended optimizations like special CPU instructions.

Comment: @YSC That's a valid interpretation, but the type of `x` matters here.

Comment: Ho. You mean `nextint` should be an overload set? Easy then.

Comment: Truncate it and add 1.

Comment: `float next = (int)(x)+1;`

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Exactly

Comment: But what about floatting points past `INT_MAX`?

Comment: More reliably `float next = floor(x)+1;`

Comment: What is the use scenario for this? Over the full range of a floating-point format, iterating through the integers would produce an uneven distribution, as it increments steadily where consecutive integers are representable but then jumps as the magnitude increases. That is not a typically useful situation. More likely, an application is using only the interval where consecutive integers are representable. In that case, it ought to be stated as a premise of the problem, and the [answer by eeroika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106882/298225) is satisfactory.

Comment: In other words, this appears to be a situation where the general case is more usefully partitioned into specific cases, because the answer for an actual case may be simpler and better than an answer for the general case. But the criteria for the cases ought to be clearly stated, so that future readers can distinguish them and are not led to use an inappropriate answer for their own situations.

Comment: That seems like the question @DmytroDadyka: what is more efficient (int)(x) + 1 more efficient than floor(x) + 1? If x does or does not hold a float value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to want floor + 1:

```
 float next = floorf(x) + 1; // or std::floor
```

Note that this gives you the mathematically next integer, rounded to nearest representable value, which for large `x` may be `x` itself. This does not produce a strictly larger representable integer in such case. You should consider whether this is what you intend.

Comment: I think this is what I want, sorry for the easy question, fighting a chest cold and just not interested in sussing this out for myself, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to get the correct result even for large floating point numbers (where the next float may be more than `1` away).

```
float nextint(float x)
{
    constexpr float MAX_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    return std::ceil(std::nextafter(x, MAX_VALUE));
}
```

First, we move to the next representable floating point value (towards positive infinity). Then we round up to the nearest floating point value.

**Proof of correctness:**

We trivially satisfy the "strictly greater" criterion because `nextafter` strictly increases the number and `ceil` never lowers it.

We never advance by more than one representable integer (that is, we actually get the "next higher" one): Either `nextafter(x)` is already the next higher *representable* integer (in which case `ceil` leaves it unchanged), or it is a float between `x` and the next higher integer (in which case `ceil` takes us to the latter).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, removed that section as there does indeed not appear to be a simple way. Apparently some platforms provide `nextup` but I can't find it in a standard (and I couldn't get it inlined either).